# Discrepancy in annotation with aggregation function (`Sum`) in Tortoise ORM

Tags: python, orm, fastapi

I'm creating a web application using Python (3.12), Fast API and Tortoise ORM (0.19.3). To make the question easier let's assume that I have three models.

```
class Rank(Model):
    rank_id = fields.IntField(pk=True)

    # relations
    user = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.User", related_name="ranks")
    duel = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.Duel", related_name="ranks")

    # the amount of points to be added to the ranking
    ranking_points = fields.FloatField(default=0)

    # the time when the verdict was obtained
    submitted = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        table = "rank"


class User(Model):
    user_id = fields.IntField(pk=True)

    # personal information
    nickname = fields.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=False)
    ranking = fields.FloatField(default=1000)

   class Meta:
       table = "user"


class Duel(Model):
    duel_id = fields.IntField(pk=True)

    # ranking information
    ranked = fields.BooleanField(default=False)

    # participants
    challenger = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.User", related_name="dares_sent")
    challenged = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.User", related_name="dares_received")
    users = fields.ManyToManyField("models.User", related_name="duels")

    # results
    loser = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.User", related_name="lost_duels", null=True)
    winner = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.User", related_name="won_duels", null=True)

    class Meta:
        table = "duel"
```

I would like to extract the information about how my users performed in Duels, i.e. I would like to extract the total amount of ranking points scored during a specified amount of time, total duels they participated in and information about the results. This is my attempt.

```
User.exclude(ranks=None).filter(ranks__submitted__gte=self.start, ranks__submitted__lte=self.end)
.annotate(score=Sum("ranks__ranking_points", distinct=True))
.annotate(ranked_won=Count("won_duels", distinct=True))
.annotate(ranked_lost=Count("lost_duels", distinct=True))
.annotate(ranked_total=Count("ranks__rank_id", distinct=True))
.prefetch_related('ranks')
.order_by("-score", "-ranking", "ranked_total")
```

To my great surprise the score annotation does not work as I expected. Please check the ranks for user with `id = 1`.

```
[
  {
    "rank_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "duel_id": 1,
    "ranking_points": 55,
    "submitted": "2024-02-07T13:39:09.988578+00:00"
  },
  {
    "rank_id": 4,
    "user_id": 1,
    "duel_id": 2,
    "ranking_points": -63,
    "submitted": "2024-02-07T13:51:42.678341+00:00"
  },
  {
    "rank_id": 5,
    "user_id": 1,
    "duel_id": 3,
    "ranking_points": 55,
    "submitted": "2024-02-07T14:00:06.287463+00:00"
  },
  {
    "rank_id": 7,
    "user_id": 1,
    "duel_id": 4,
    "ranking_points": 2,
    "submitted": "2024-02-07T14:07:42.970595+00:00"
  },
  {
    "rank_id": 10,
    "user_id": 1,
    "duel_id": 5,
    "ranking_points": -50,
    "submitted": "2024-02-07T14:30:27.638658+00:00"
  },
  {
    "rank_id": 12,
    "user_id": 1,
    "duel_id": 6,
    "ranking_points": -66,
    "submitted": "2024-02-07T14:42:56.860867+00:00"
  }
]
```

I think that the correct score value should be `55 - 63 + 55 + 2 - 50 - 66 = -67` however the query returns `-122`. Why? How can I fix this behavior? Is my query wrong or is there a bug in Tortoise ORM?

P. S.
I have doubled checked the date ranges thus it's not it.